# 404 Not Foud in conventional routing

Tags: asp.net-core

I am following the tutorial in microsoft.com (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) with VS Code and dotnet CLI tools. I cannot access this controller through the URL: https://localhost:5001/api/Todo.

```
namespace TodoApi2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoContoller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoContoller(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
        }
...
```

But the following works

```
namespace TodoApi2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Todo")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoContoller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoContoller(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
        {
            return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
        }
...
```

No idea why the convention [controller] not work.

Comment: 404=no matching view. add view or check in  postman

Comment: I have tried in both postman and chrome and have no luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your controller name is **`TodoContoller`** instead of **`TodoController`**.

To fix it, change your code as below :

```
    public class TodoContoller : ControllerBase 
    public class TodoController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...

        public TodoContoller(TodoContext context) 
        public TodoController(TodoContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        } 
    }
```